# Javascript to wait 5 seconds before next item.click with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Trying to determine proper Javascript syntax to combine the following:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("css-1ku3j26")).forEach(function(item) 
{
   item.click();});
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() 
  {
    statement2();
  }, 5000);
```

Objective is a 5 second delay between each "item.click" requested...

Totally new to Javascript, and can't figure out proper syntax.

EDIT:

I think @Juan Melnechuk's answer is very close to achieving my goal; hoping code will automatically expand/toggle the transactions on the following wbpage:

https://marketplace.draftkings.com/listings/packs/e2abd0b01379468d87a64ab5c2fe37b5

[image: Expandable info]

Note: appears ClassName at issue should be "css-1r52ixm" (not css-1ku3j26)

@Juan Melnechuk's proposal:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("css-1r52ixm")).forEach(function(item, index) 
{
  setTimeout(function() 
  {
    item.click();
  }, 5000 * (index + 1));
});
```

seems to provide progress, but not entirely.

Comment: Why do you want to wait 5 seconds? Are the togglables added in that frequency? Why not react to DOM mutations (via the [`MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver))?

Comment: "Why do you want to wait 5 seconds? Are the togglables added in that frequency?"  I think the host wants to prevent automated expansion; so I thought by incorporating a delay, that would allow a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index as multiplier:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("css-1ku3j26")).forEach(function(item, index) 
{
  setTimeout(function() 
  {
    item.click();
  }, 5000 * (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: This will result in clicking all the items after just 5 seconds total. The question wants you to wait 5 seconds between each item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it, perhaps, using a recursive function. Maybe it'll provide some insight.

```js
let items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("css-1ku3j26"));

document.body.addEventListener( "click", handleClick, false );

function itemsClick () {
  if ( items.length > 0 ) {
    items.pop().click();
    setTimeout( itemsClick, 500 );
  }
}

function handleClick(evt) {
  let e = evt.target;
  if (e.matches("button.css-1ku3j26")) {
     e.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}

itemsClick();
```

```css
button {
 margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<button class="css-1ku3j26">button 1</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">button 2</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">button 3</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">button 4</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">button 5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Juan Melnechuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527191/4476484) will get the job done if you care about *starting* each `click` call at even intervals. But if your `click` function takes a variable amount of time and you care about waiting 5 seconds *between* `click` calls rather than 5 seconds between the *start* of each `click` call, then you would want to use promises. For example:

```js
// create a delay function
const wait = async (delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
};

// get a list of all the items
const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("css-1ku3j26"));

// async context
(async () => {
    // loop over the items and delay 5 seconds between each call
    for (const item of items) {
        await delay(5000);
        item.click();
    }
})();
```

If your `click` function takes a variable amount of time between 0 ms and 1000 ms to run, and you use the `5000 * index` method, then you're going to have some inconsistency where the timing will not be even. If you use this asynchronous method, then you'll be guaranteed 5 seconds between the Nth `click` *finishing* and the (N+1)th `click` *starting*.

So just be aware of this and choose whichever kind of method works best for your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@Gary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527228/13561410), but this implementation does not depend on outside variables.

It clicks all elements of list `elements`, after a delay of `ms` initially and between each click:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("css-1ku3j26");

clickDelayed(elements, 5000);

function clickDelayed(elements, ms = 1000) {
  function clickNext(elements, i = 0) {
    if (i >= elements.length) return;
    
    try {
      elements[i].click();
    } finally {
      // Click next delayed, even on error
      setTimeout(clickNext, ms, elements, ++i);
    }
  }

  // Start delayed clicking
  setTimeout(clickNext, ms, Array.from(elements));
}

/*Ignore; make buttons log content on click*/
document.body.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (evt.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    console.log(evt.target.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="css-1ku3j26">1</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">2</button>
<button class="css-1ku3j26">3</button>
```

By copying `elements` (see [`Array.from(elements)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)), modifications to it won't affect which elements will be clicked nor the order. (Remove the copying if this feature is unwanted.)

The delayed clicking continues even if an item is not clickable (see the [finally-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#finallystatements)). The error of trying to click it will still be logged.

Notice how the parameters `ms` and `elements` are used in the `clickNext` function:

- The parameter `ms` is declared in `clickDelayed`, but used in `clickNext`. Because `clickNext` makes use of an outside scope, it creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) around it. Basically, `ms` is the *same variable* in both contexts.
- The parameter `elements` is declared in both `clickDelayed` and its inner function `clickNext`. They are *different variables of similar name*. When this happens in nested scopes (e.g. here) it is called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

---

This mix of "variable from outside scope" and "variable from this scope" is subjective.

- To avoid closures altogether, the parameter `ms` could be passed to the inner function as well.
- To remove non-changing variables from `clickNext`'s parameter list, we could reference an outside variable for the copied list e.g. `copiedElements` declared in `clickDelayed`.
- To remove all parameters for `setTimeout`'s callback, we could declare `i` in `clickDelayed`.

I chose the implementation as shown for these (subjective) reasons:

- Parameter `ms` is user-provided and non-changing, so there should only exist one variable for it; the outer function's parameter.
- Parameter `i` is only used in the callback, therefore it should only be declared in the callback.
- I want `elements` to provide the (order of) items to click. Later changes to it may be confusing, so I want to work on a copy of it.

  *The parameter list shows relevant variables at a glance*, so by "re-declaring" `elements` in `clickNext` we show that it is important for that function's execution.

  In comparison, parameter `ms` is *not* important for `clickNext`'s execution, but for its *timing*. I'd argue this is not `clickNext`'s responsibility but `clickDelayed`'s, so `ms` does not belong into `clickNext`'s parameter list.

---

The responsibility issue could be better reflected by replacing `clickNext` with two functions: One for the recursion (the base condition and the iteration step) and another for clicking, to be called in the first.

But at some point you are [over-engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) and should stop.

Answer (score 0):

Just shift them off the array and call the function over and over until you are out. Basic queue.

```js
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'));

(function clickNext () {
  items.shift()?.click();
  if (items.length) window.setTimeout(clickNext, 5000);
})();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```